# J2ME - How to convert double to string without the power to 10 representation (E-05)

Tags: java-me

I have a double value . I want to store it in String with out E notation (in J2ME)

Example

Double value 6.887578324E9
Want to show as 6887578342

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own method to do that, or use some already existing library.
Javolution, for example, gives you the class and method
TypeFormat.format(double d, int digits, boolean scientific, boolean showZero, Appendable a) 
Check [Javolution](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/text/TypeFormat.html), it has lots of nice utilities,  but if the only thing you need is to format numbers, just write your own method.
Here is a quick hack for big numbers

```
    private static String nosci(double d) {
    if(d < 0){
        return "-" + nosci(-d);
    }
    String javaString = String.valueOf(d);
    int indexOfE =javaString.indexOf("E"); 
    if(indexOfE == -1){
        return javaString;
    }
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if(d > 1){//big number
        int exp = Integer.parseInt(javaString.substring(indexOfE + 1));
        String sciDecimal = javaString.substring(2, indexOfE);
        int sciDecimalLength = sciDecimal.length();
        if(exp == sciDecimalLength){
            sb.append(javaString.charAt(0));
            sb.append(sciDecimal);              
        }else if(exp > sciDecimalLength){
            sb.append(javaString.charAt(0));
            sb.append(sciDecimal);
            for(int i = 0; i < exp - sciDecimalLength; i++){
                sb.append('0');
            }
        }else if(exp < sciDecimalLength){
            sb.append(javaString.charAt(0));
            sb.append(sciDecimal.substring(0, exp));
            sb.append('.');
            for(int i = exp; i < sciDecimalLength ; i++){
                sb.append(sciDecimal.charAt(i));
            }
        }
      return sb.toString();
    }else{
        //for little numbers use the default or you will
        //loose accuracy
        return javaString;
    }       


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this article: [Converting Double to String without E notation](http://technopaper.blogspot.com/2009/06/converting-double-to-string-without-e.html)

You can make use of the `[NumberFormat][2]` or `[DecimalFormat][3]` class to acheive what you are looking for.

Here is the code:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance();
f.setGroupingUsed(false);
String refinedNumber = f.format(doubleVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think NumberFormat is available only in JAVA. Not in J2ME.

Comment: well, they seems to be available: http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/fp1.1.2/jsr219/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: NumberFormat is java.text . When I try to import java.text I can see only java.io.*, java.lang.*, java.lang.ref.*, java.nio.*, java.rmi.*, java.util.* under “java. “. Am I missing something? I am using blackberry Java plug-in for Eclipse. Let me try ...

Comment: I don't think its going to work :(. have a look at this: http://www.java-forums.org/netbeans/14363-package-java-text-does-not-exist.html (At the end, they take about blackberry as well)

Comment: -1 `NumberFormat` is not available in [Java ME CLDC](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/index.html) versions 1.0 (JSR 37) and 1.1 (JSR 139)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java `Formatter`, just specify how many decimals do you want with the string.

E.g. a double converted to a number with one decimal:

```
Formatter format = new Formatter();
String mystring = format.formatNumber(DOUBLENUMBERVARIABLE,1);
System.out.println(mystring );
```

Comment: J2ME doesnt have a Formatter class.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use piece of code below, but not for j2me.

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleVariable)
```

Comment: -1 `BigDecimal` is not available in [Java ME CLDC](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/index.html) versions 1.0 (JSR 37) and 1.1 (JSR 139)

Comment: ooh you are right I just missed the J2me keyword.  the sentence I wrote above is very assertive. thank you for your comment.