# How convert double to String?

Tags: android

I have code:

```
double total = 36183063.0;
String val = String.valueOf(total);
```

Why its coming `val="3.6183063E7"`?

instead of `val="36183063"`.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287716/j2me-how-to-convert-double-to-string-without-the-power-to-10-representation-e

Comment: [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(double)) is overloaded for int and double values (and even some more!).

So you're using `valueOf(double d)`. You should cast it to `int` before or use `Double.toString(double d)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
double total = 36183063.0;
String val = String.valueOf((long)total);
```

Comment: if double total = 36183063.23; String val = String.valueOf((long)total); val=" 36183063";

Answer (score 2):

Use Double class provided toString(Double d) method

like below,

```
double total = 36183063.0;
String val = Double.toString(total);
```

Comment: I use String str = Double.toString(total); val ="3.6183063E7"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Double.toString(val);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String str = Double.toString(total);
```

OR,

```
String str = String.valueOf((long)total);
```

Comment: I use String str = Double.toString(total); val ="3.6183063E7".

Comment: I use String str = total+""; val="36183063.0"